# How can I write clean and effective pronunciation puzzles?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there were a special way for pronunciation-based puzzles to be made, where the puzzle revolves around homophones.

As an example, distinguishing between pi and pie - how do I communicate both, without giving the puzzle away?

Comment: Related: [1](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1407), [2](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4612)

Comment: Can you build a story around your puzzle so that you HEAR one of the characters say "xxxxx"?